# My click trigger always fire in google tag manager

Tags: triggers, google-tag-manager

I'm having difficulties using the Click trigger in google tag manager.

I want to setup a trigger to fire on a click event, only when the element class contain "scrollto".

But the thing is, it keeps firing up even when the "scrollto" class isn't part of the element I clicked on.

Here are a few screenshot I hope will help you understand the problem:

[image]

[image]

Thank you for your help,
Alexis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ones you set up any click trigger you will get these events everytime a user makes a click but that doesnt mean the trigger it self is being fired. You can append the trigger to any tag and you ll see that if you click anywhere else the tag wont fire even when you see the event.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. You are right, I the tag isn't fired and everything works accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of click classes contains scrollto, 
Give click classes equals scrollto